# swift combine sink receiveValue memory leak

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, combine

I'm having a hard time with dealing with Combine. After the publisher is complete I want to update a value but whenever I update that value the memory is allocated and never goes away.

Whenever I try to assign image there is a leak. If I don't assign no leak.

EDIT: Reproducible example here: https://github.com/peterwarbo/MemoryAllocation

This is what my code looks like:

```
final class CameraController: ObservableObject {

    private var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()    
    var image: UIImage?

    func capture(_ image: UIImage) {

        PhotoLibrary.saveImageToTemporaryDirectory(image) // AnyPublisher<URL, Error>
            .zip(PhotoLibrary.saveImage(image, location: self.locationObserver.location) // AnyPublisher<UIImage, Error>)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { [weak self] (completion) in
                switch completion {
                case let .failure(error):
                    Log.error(error)
                    self?.handleCaptureError(error)
                case .finished: break
                }
            }) { [weak self] (value) in
                print(value.1) // no leak
                self.image = value.1 // leak

            }
            .store(in: &self.storage)
     }
}
```

I've also tried instead of using `sink`:

```
.receive(
    subscriber: Subscribers.Sink(
        receiveCompletion: { [weak self] completion in
            switch completion {
            case let .failure(error):
                Log.error(error)
                self?.handleCaptureError(error)
            case .finished: break
            }
        },
        receiveValue: { value in
            print(value.1) // no leak
            self.image = value.1 // leak            
        }
    )
)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An obvious problem with your code is that you create and store a new pipeline every time `capture` is called. That is the opposite of how to use Combine; you might as well not be using Combine at all. The way to use Combine is to create a pipeline *once* and let information come down the pipeline asynchronously from then on.

You posted an example project in which you use a Future to introduce a delay in the passing of an image down a pipeline. In your project, the user chooses an image from the photo library, repeatedly. Once again, in your project you create and store a new pipeline every time an image is chosen. I rewrote the example as follows:

```
import UIKit
import Combine

class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Queue", qos: .userInitiated, attributes: [], autoreleaseFrequency: .workItem)
    var image: UIImage?
    var storage: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    let publisher = PassthroughSubject<UIImage, Never>()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.publisher
            .flatMap {image in
                self.futureMaker(image: image)
            }
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { (completion) in
            }) { (value) in
                print("finished processing image")
                self.image = value
            }
            .store(in: &self.storage)
    }
    @IBAction func didTapPickImage(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = self
        present(picker, animated: true)
    }
    func futureMaker(image: UIImage) -> AnyPublisher<UIImage, Never> {
        Future<UIImage, Never> { promise in
            self.queue.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                promise(.success(image))
            }
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
extension ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        dismiss(animated: true)
        guard let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage else { return }
        print("got image")
        self.publisher.send(image)
    }
}
```

Note the architecture: I create the pipeline once, in `viewDidLoad`, and whenever an image arrives I pass it down the *same* pipeline. Some memory is used, to be sure, because we are storing a UIImage; but it does not grow in any uncontrolled way, but levels off in an optimal manner.

[image]

We're using 8.4 MB after picking all the images in the library repeatedly. No problem there!

[image]

Also, no surplus large images are persisting. Looking at memory that comes from choosing in the image picker, *one* image persists; that is 2.7 MB of our 8.4 MB:

[image]

That is exactly what we expect.

Comment: You might want to read my online tutorial on Combine: http://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/

Comment: Thanks Matt, I'll try out your solution. Is there a way to get more compact syntax without involving variables for the publisher and pipeline? I'm trying to achieve "promise like" syntax with using combine and no 3rd party libs.

Comment: It depends on what you're really trying to accomplish. But the publisher must live _somewhere_. The photo library does not vend a publisher of its image, so _someone_ must vend it. But that doesn't _make_ one every time. Just the opposite. That's my point.

Comment: Trying to achieve similar functionality as in this thread (https://stackoverflow.com/q/59428026/294661). Basically I have a few async methods, some can be performed in parallel and after they performed I want to chain another async method. What I've used before is PromiseKit but I wanted to try to achieve it with combines Future. Maybe combine is not the right fit for my needs?

Comment: I'm sure it is. It is where native Promises are kept (sorry about that). And Combine is exactly about "some can be performed in parallel and after.. I want to chain another". It's perfect for that. What's the question? Sorry, I got a bit lost. It seems to me I answered the original question...? Did you read my tutorial?

Comment: I updated my pull request to reorganize more like what you seem to have in mind.

Comment: Much obliged Matt. Thanks for your solution(s)!

Answer (score 1):

Just by code reading... use weak self, not direct self,

```
}) { [weak self] (value) in
    print(value.1) // no leak
    self?.image = value.1     // << here !!
    self?.storage.removeAll() // just in case
}
```

also I would add delivery on main queue, as

```
PhotoLibrary.saveImageToTemporaryDirectory(image)
    .zip(PhotoLibrary.saveImage(image, location: self.locationObserver.location)
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)          // << here !!
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { [weak self] (completion) in
    // ... other code here
```

Comment: That didn't help unfortunately :(

Comment: @PeterWarbo, ok, it is impossible to solve by guessing.. it needs some reproducible example.

Comment: here's a reproducible example: https://github.com/peterwarbo/MemoryAllocation

Comment: @PeterWarbo Your test is wrong. You say: Go into Debug navigator. Click on memory. In simulator click on "Pick image" and choose an image. Watch memory grow every time an image is picked. — Simulator memory management in a debug build  tells you nothing. Test on a device and use Instruments; that way, measurement is correct, plus if you have a leak you will know what it is and why

Comment: @PeterWarbo also your threading looks wrong. Your pipeline runs on background threads and you never switch to the main thread before setting properties of self.

Comment: @PeterWarbo and your use of Combine is wrong. You are creating and storing a whole new pipeline every time you fetch an image.

Comment: @matt If you have a device then of course it's better to test on device, great point. About threading I don't think it matters in this case since I'm not updating any UI I'm only setting a variable. How do you suggest I use combine for doing a one-off async operation? I'm following this guide: https://www.donnywals.com/using-promises-and-futures-in-combine/

Comment: Well the point is that it isn't one-off. You say "Watch memory grow every time an image is picked." But every time an image is picked, you are making a whole new pipeline. That's the opposite of one-off, it's every-off. :)

Comment: @PeterWarbo I forked your repo and pushed a pull request that shows one way to use combine cleanly here. Memory does not grow and grow; the needle in the gauge stays pegged at the bottom. Sure, some memory is used, but it levels off. There are some _tiny_ leaks in Apple's code but that's not your problem.

Answer (score -1):

You are using .store(in: &self.storage)

need to cancel this  private var storage = Set()

storage.cancel()
storage.removeAll()

and also self need to be weak