# Chain network calls sequentially in Combine

Tags: swift, combine

My goal is to chain multiple (two at this time) network calls with Combine, breaking chain if first call fails.

I have two object types: `CategoryEntity` and `SubcategoryEntity`. Every `CategoryEntity` has a property called `subcategoriesIDS`.
With first call I need to fetch all subcategories, with second I will fetch all categories and then I will create an array of `CategoryEntityViewModel`.
`CategoryEntityViewModel` contains an array of `SubcategoryEntityViewModel` based on `CategoryEntity`'s `subcategoriesIDS`.

Just to be clearer:

1. Fetch subcategories
2. Fetch categories
3. Create a `SubcategoryEntityViewModel` for every fetched subcategory and store somewhere
4. `CategoryEntityViewModel` is created for every category fetched. This object will be initialized with a `CategoryEntity` object and an array of `SubcategoryEntityViewModel`, found filtering matching ids between `subcategoriesIDS` and stored `SubcategoryEntityViewModel` array

My code right now is:

```
class CategoriesService: Service, ErrorManager {
    static let shared = CategoriesService()
    internal let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    
    @Published var error: ServerError = .none
    
    private init() {
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategyFormatters = [ DateFormatter.yearMonthDay ]
    }
    
    func getAllCategories() -> AnyPublisher<[CategoryEntity], ServerError> {
        let request = self.createRequest(withUrlString: "\(AppSettings.api_endpoint)/categories/all", forMethod: .get)
        return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .tryMap { data, response -> Data in
                guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, 200..<300 ~= httpResponse.statusCode else {
                    switch (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode {
                    case (401):
                        throw ServerError.notAuthorized
                    default:
                        throw ServerError.unknown
                    }
                }
                return data
            }
            .map { $0 }
            .decode(type: NetworkResponse<[CategoryEntity]>.self, decoder: self.decoder)
            .map { $0.result}
            .mapError { error -> ServerError in self.manageError(error: error)}
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    func getAllSubcategories() -> AnyPublisher<[SubcategoryEntity], ServerError> {
        let request = self.createRequest(withUrlString: "\(AppSettings.api_endpoint)/subcategories/all", forMethod: .get)
        return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .tryMap { data, response -> Data in
                guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, 200..<300 ~= httpResponse.statusCode else {
                    switch (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode {
                    case (401):
                        throw ServerError.notAuthorized
                    default:
                        throw ServerError.unknown
                    }
                }
                return data
            }
            .map { $0 }
            .decode(type: NetworkResponse<[SubcategoryEntity]>.self, decoder: self.decoder)
            .map { $0.result }
            .mapError { error -> ServerError in self.manageError(error: error)}
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

These methods are working (`sink` is called in another class, don't think it is useful so not copied here) but I cannot find the correct way to chain them.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61841254/combine-framework-how-to-process-each-element-of-array-asynchronously-before-pr

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59743938/combine-framework-serialize-async-operations

Answer (score 2):

The way to chain async operations with Combine is `flatMap`. Produce the second publisher inside the map function. Be sure to pass any needed info as a value down into the map function so the second publisher can use it. See [How to replicate PromiseKit-style chained async flow using Combine + Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59428026/how-to-replicate-promisekit-style-chained-async-flow-using-combine-swift) for a basic example.