# Combine uncollect operator?

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I'm looking for an operator that does the opposite of the [collect](https://heckj.github.io/swiftui-notes/#reference-collect) operator:

- Allows you to map from one emission value to many emission values, emitting them on the stream. For example if I have the element `[1,2,3]` in the stream, I want to convert it into a stream that emits `1` then `2`, then `3`.
- Does not change the stream's completion state. Admittedly this `uncollect` operator wouldn't be exactly the opposite of `collect` since `collect` waits until the stream is finished. With `uncollect` it should just process results while the stream is unfinished, and not attempt to finish/unfinish the stream.

For example, I imagine this is how an `uncollect` operator would function:

```
func fibonacci(_ number: Int) -> AnyPublisher<Int, Never> {
  Future { ... }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

let serverEventStream: AnyPublisher<[Int], Never> = ...

serverEventStream              // AnyPublisher<[Int], Never>  // Ex. 2 values: `[12, 24]`, `[1, 10, 50]`
  .uncollect { $0 }            // AnyPublisher<Int, Never>    // Ex. 5 values: `12`, `24`, `1`, `10`, `50`
  .flatMap { fibonacci($0) }   // AnyPublisher<Int, Never>    // Ex. 5 values: `144`, `46368`, `1`, `55`, `12586269025`
  .sink { print($0) }
```

I was looking for names like `explode`, `splat`, or `uncollect`, to no avail. The closest operator that shares a promising name is [`flatMap`](https://heckj.github.io/swiftui-notes/#reference-flatmap) since [`Sequence.flatMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2905332-flatmap) is the equivalent in the non-Combine world. However, [Combine's `flatMap` is the way to chain promises together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59428026/how-to-replicate-promisekit-style-chained-async-flow-using-combine-swift).

Is there a way to uncollect elements, or map a single emission into an arbitrary number of emissions?

---

I was able to get it to work with my [custom `JustSeveral` Publisher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67523545/35690), but this seems clunky:

```
class Tests: XCTestCase {
  func testUncollect() {
    func fibonacci(_ number: Int) -> AnyPublisher<Int, Never> {
      switch number {
      case 1: return Just(1).eraseToAnyPublisher()
      case 10: return Just(55).eraseToAnyPublisher()
      case 12: return Just(144).eraseToAnyPublisher()
      case 24: return Just(46368).eraseToAnyPublisher()
      case 50: return Just(12586269025).eraseToAnyPublisher()
      default: fatalError("Should actually build this function.")
      }
    }

    let serverEventStream: AnyPublisher<[Int], Never> = JustSeveral([[12, 24], [1, 10, 50]]).eraseToAnyPublisher()

    serverEventStream              // AnyPublisher<[Int], Never>  // Ex. 2 values: `[12, 24]`, `[1, 10, 50]`
      .uncollect { $0 }            // AnyPublisher<Int, Never>    // Ex. 5 values: `12`, `24`, `1`, `10`, `50`
      .flatMap { fibonacci($0) }   // AnyPublisher<Int, Never>    // Ex. 5 values: `144`, `46368`, `1`, `55`, `12586269025`
      .sink { print($0) }
  }
}

extension Publisher {
  func uncollect<T>(_ transform: @escaping (Output) -> [T]) -> AnyPublisher<T, Failure> {
    self
      .flatMap { output -> AnyPublisher<T, Failure> in
        JustSeveral(transform(output))
          .setFailureType(to: Failure.self)
          .eraseToAnyPublisher()
      }
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` together with a new publisher

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6].publisher
    .collect()
    .flatMap { $0.publisher }
    .sink { print($0) }
```

> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5
> 6

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Turns out I [missed the Sequence.publisher documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67523504/just-with-several-values#comment119350006_67523663).

Comment: You might want `flatMap(maxPublishers: 1) { ... }` depending on how the inner publishers work.